# Add SSL keystore file to java trusted store for HTTP Client request on PCF (Cloud Foundry)

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

In my spring boot application I making a https(secure) request. For that I need pass flowing argument as JVM argument.

javax.net.ssl.trustStore
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword

Eg :

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=~/home/dinusha/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass
```

In PCF (Cloud Foundry) I can not copy keystore.jks file to PCF. So how can I pass this values on PCF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to bundle the **keystore.jks** file with application. Please find the step bellow.

1. Put your keystore.jks file into you application resources(src/main/resources) folder.
2. Add the keystore.jks path and it's password in the **application.properties**

   > client.ssl.trust-store = keystore.jks 
   >   client.ssl.trust-password = pass
3. Now get the property value form application.properties

   > @value("${client.ssl.trust-password}") 
   >   private String trustPassword
   >   @value("${client.ssl.trust-store}") 
   >   private String trustStore
4. Now initialize flowing properties

   > System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
   >   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",trustPassword);
5. Finaly push to PCF

Comment: KO for me: trustStorFile seems not be reachable when under /resources within jar, by simply setting its filename as the value of javax.net.ssl.trustStore, whereas it works when left outside the jar with path relative to current execution context.(System.getProperty("user.dir"))

Answer (score -2):

Best to refer and store Keystore.jks and trustStrore.jks is to outsiode your application (WAR , JAR , EAR).

And yes , for request you donot neend ketstore instead you require **truststore.jks.**

You can store it in GIT or some othe Repo location and point to that location from your application via CloundFoundry.

Put your keystore.jks file into you application resources(src/main/resources) folder.

```
Add the Truststore.jks path and it's password in the application.properties

*client.ssl.trust-store = keystore.jks

client.ssl.trust-password = pass*
```

Now get the property value form application.properties

```
@value("${client.ssl.trust-password}")
private String trustPassword

@value("${client.ssl.trust-store}")
private String trustStore


    Put the location with protocol details in manifest file like below :

    env:
      loglevel: DEBUG,APP
      JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
      TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: https://XXXX:yyyyyy@svninst1.uk.fid-intl.com:18080/svn/TAPP100367DC_API/trunk/dc-Member-Api/dc-Member-Api-web/src/main/resources/cacerts.jks

and get it like:

@value("${client.ssl.trust-password}")
private String trustPassword

@value("${TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION}")
private String trustStore
```