# JaxB not Unmarshalling due to SSL error on cloud foundry?

Tags: jdbc, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, cloud-foundry

I have an web application, Using thymeleaf, springboot, angularjs, and oracle sql developer db.

Locally I am able to connect and get values from oracle. But when I push my application to cloud foundry, I am getting status=500.

**ERROR**

The url that I am unmarshalling has a untrusted certificate ("Your connection is not secured)". I added cacerts into my jvm, which allowed it to work locally. but I believe I need to add the cacerts into cloud foundry. How would I be able to do so?

**SSL error**

```
 ERR java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out  
 ERR at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  
 ERR at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)  
 ERR at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)  
 ERR at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)  
 ERR at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)  
 ERR at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  
 ERR at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)  
 ERR at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)  
 ERR at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)  
 ERR at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)  
 ERR at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)  
 ERR at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)  
 ERR at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)  
 ERR at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)  
 ERR at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)  
 ERR at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)  
 ERR at rest.springframework.controllers.IndexController.getDetails(IndexController.java:59)  
 ERR at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
 ERR at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
 ERR at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
```

**ERR at rest.springframework.jaxb.JAXSample.readXML(JAXSample.java:34)**

**Reason**

I removed jaxB unmarshalling from my application and uploaded into cloud foundry and I was did not get status=500. How can I add SSL to prevent this from happening?

**JaxB Sample**

```
public deviceCert readXML(String MAC) throws MalformedURLException {
  results customer = null;
  deviceCert dcert = null;
  String APPKEY = "Production";

  try {
      JAXBContext jaxbContext  = JAXBContext.newInstance(results.class);
      //line 34 is below VV.
      URL url = new URL("https://untrusted.page.that.I.Am/unmarshalling" + "?mac=" + MAC + "&app_key=" + APPKEY);

      HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 

      http.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76"); 
      InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      customer = (results) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is);

      List<deviceCert> dcerts = customer.getDcerts();
      dcert = dcerts.get(0);
```

Found related link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391896/pivotal-cloud-foundry-security-certificates?rq=1)

I followed [CF CLI SSL](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/self-signed.html) But that did not do the trick.

**Attempt**

1. Created folders resources/config/truststore in my application.
2. Added Cert.cer into truststore folder.
3. Pushed app to cloud foundry.
4. cf set-env my-app JAVA_OPTS '-Djavax.net.ssl.TrustStore=classpath:resources/config/truststore'

*Same error nothings changed.*

**Attempt 2**

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>cloudfoundry-certificate-truster</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

1. added dependency
2. Repackaged app, upload to cf.
3. Added environment variable on cloud foundry

   CF_TARGET=https://api.my-cf-domain.com

   ```
              //url of my secured/untrusted page
   ```

[Github example](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/cloudfoundry-certificate-truster)

**New StackTrace error**

```
ERR at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
ERR at io.pivotal.springcloud.ssl.SslCertificateTruster.getUntrustedCertificateInternal(SslCertificateTruster.java:90)
ERR at io.pivotal.springcloud.ssl.SslCertificateTruster.getUntrustedCertificate(SslCertificateTruster.java:66)
ERR at io.pivotal.springcloud.ssl.CloudFoundryCertificateTruster.trustCertificatesInternal(CloudFoundryCertificateTruster.java:44)
ERR at io.pivotal.springcloud.ssl.CloudFoundryCertificateTruster.trustCertificates(CloudFoundryCertificateTruster.java:32)
ERR at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:420)
ERR at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:403)
ERR at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:394)
ERR at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:261)
ERR at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:237)
ERR at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
ERR at rest.springframework.SpringBootWebApplication.main(SpringBootWebApplication.java:13)
ERR at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
ERR at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
ERR at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
ERR at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
ERR at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
```

Why does this work find locally but not on the cloud?

Comment: "Do I need a cloud profile?" - yes, and possibly a firewall rule to allow PCF to connect to an Oracle database that isn't running on cloud.

Comment: @duffymo for the cloud config. do I just add cloud.datasource.url etc....

Comment: I think you also need a service to be attached to the instance.

Comment: Also, check your logs.  A 500 error means that your app failed and there's a stack trace in the logs to tell you why it failed.  That should provide clues about what's happening.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Thank you, I looked at my stack trace and I believe it has to do with SSL.

Comment: Is the value of `spring.datasource.url` your actual value?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No it's a representation of what I've put. My value is simliar to "spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@//spring.guru.csi0i9rgj9ws.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/ORC"

Comment: A _Connection timed out_ usually means that the host isn't reachable. You might want to check firewall rules, etc.

Comment: Use `cf space YOUR_SPACE --security-group-rules` to display the security rules applied to your running application by CF. Ensure the domain (or its IP address) in your "spring.datasource.url" is in there, with port 1521 and protocol tcp (or a security group rule wide enough to cover it).

Comment: @dkoper I dont see my spring.datasource.url.  I see my org, apps, domains, services, Then I see protocol: all and destination : xxx:xx:xxx

Comment: @Jesse If your app can access the DB when JAXB is taken out, you must have a rule in one of your security groups that allows access to it. For example, my CF installation has a rule with "destination   :   11.0.0.0-169.253.255.255" and "protocol      :   all" that gives it access to most of the cloud services on the Internet that I know.

Comment: I tried adding the Java_Opts you provided in the answer below. But that did not do the trick. My current destination shows 00:00:00:255:255:255

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to add a CA cert to your container:
https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/223454928-How-to-tell-application-containers-running-Java-apps-to-trust-self-signed-certs-or-a-private-internal-CA

The easiest one is probably to point the Java VM to a cacert file you bundle in your app, using `cf set-env <app> JAVA_OPTS '-Djavax.net.ssl.TrustStore=classpath:resources/config/truststore'` or with the "env" attribute in your app manifest.

Comment: I did what you said set-env. and i restaged my application it still does not work. I am still getting the same error as the stack trace above.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer to your actual problem, which looks more network related that cert related.  But to provide some other solutions for SSL / cert trust issues, you can check out this slide from a presentation I gave -> https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1GQ2qrFT3rNJ6L2PURmNfEkKdQhed_vI23Q0hopVFd0o/edit#slide=id.g154ee7fa13_0_13

Comment: @DanielMikusa I found concrete evidence that it is the SSL problem. When I removed jaxB from my application it worked.

Comment: I also followed https://github.com/pivotal-cf/cloudfoundry-certificate-truster. It did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you control your CloudFoundry platform then you can use the following approach::

1) Add certs via ops manager for PCF or via bosh http://bosh.io/docs/trusted-certs.html

2) Configure buildpack to use custom certificate trust store.

cf set-env app JBP_CONFIG_CONTAINER_CERTIFICATE_TRUST_STORE ‘{enabled: true}'

Links:

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/bosh_custom_trusted_certs.html

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/README.md#configuration-and-extension

Answer (score 0):

Fist you have to create jks file for downloaded certificate. You can find keytool from JDK bin.

> keytool -importcert -file "your.cer" -keystore your.jks -alias "testAlias"

Add your.jks file as a resource in spring-boot project.

set path and password of certificate store using configuration in application.properties
eg:

```
your.ssl.trust-store = your.jks
your.ssl.trust-password = changeit
```

Load it from application startup.

Eg:

```
public class LoadSSLTrustStore implements CommandLineRunner{


       @Value("${your.ssl.trust-store}")
        private  String keyUrl;
       @Value("${your.ssl.trust-password}")
       private  String keyPassword;
    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        try{
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",CustomerMasterServiceApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResource(keyUrl).getFile());
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",keyPassword);

        }catch(Exception e){
            LOGGER.error("Error in loading SSL trusted key store for Connect to GCIN service",e);
        }

    }

}
```

Related question

[Add SSL keystore file to java trusted store for HTTP Client request on PCF (Cloud Foundry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263524/add-ssl-keystore-file-to-java-trusted-store-for-http-client-request-on-pcf-clou)

Comment: I saved my .crt as a .jks with command prompt. added credentials in my app.properties file. and created a class to load ssl trust store. Followed your example from the link u provided. But I am still receiving the same errror