# Have added Weblogic certificates to local JDK cacerts.How to add certificates in PCF so I can sucessfully connect to Weblogic Jms through mulesoft

Tags: java, weblogic, mulesoft, pcf

I have succesfully connected to Weblogic JMS through Mulesoft in my local system.
I have added Root certificates and IntermediateSigner certificates from Weblogic to my local JDK cacerts so I can connect to Weblogic JMS.By this way Iam able to sucessfully connect in my local system. But now I want to deploy my application to PCF, how can I add these certificates so my mulesoft code and weblogic jms queues can sucessfully connect in PCF too.

Thanks
Pallavi

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Pallavi! Please give some context - what do you mean by PCF? Pivotal Cloud Foundry? Also, please make the question title a bit more succinct, and split the question into multiple paragraphs in a way that makes sense, so it is easier for users to answer your question.

Comment: I am not familiar with the topic, but does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399137/jaxb-not-unmarshalling-due-to-ssl-error-on-cloud-foundry

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Java default trust store file (cacerts) is not a good idea in my opinion. It is better to put the certificates in a separate trust store file, even using a copy of cacerts if needed, and set the new one as the default trust store using the Java properties:

Trust store file: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore.file
Trust store password: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=....
Trust store type: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=... (if the trust store file is not using the default type)

This makes it much easier to track and manage configurations.

I'm not sure if you can set the trust store in this way in PCF.